# How do I use Boot Repairs Manager without internet connection?

Tags: 12.04

I'm unable to repair Ubuntu 12.04 boot with Boot Repairs Manager
as it asks for internet connection.

How do I use Boot Repairs Manager without internet connection?

Comment: just skip the step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires internet probably because it needs to download some GRUB packages.

See https://answers.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+question/218370